# "error MSB1009: Project file does not exist." when deploying asp.net project with bamboo

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, umbraco, bamboo

I'm trying to deploy an umbraco project with bamboo. My .sln file on repository has [such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxDG5.png) a path. My deployment task looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDNnv.png) (I also tried other paths, none of them is work).

When I try to deploy the project i receive the following error:

```
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Switch: .\TestUmbraco\TestUmbraco.sln
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Failing task since return code of [C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe @C:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\753667-819204-1015822-MsBuildTaskType-5692714942676123236.rsp] was 1 while expected 0
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Finished task 'MSBuild' with result: Failed
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Finalising the build...
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Stopping timer.
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Build 753667-819204-1015822 completed.
01-Jan-1970 03:00:00    Finished processing deployment result Deployment of 'release-1' on 'TestUmbracoEnvironment'
```

I was surprized that I couldn't find a way to resolve this problem on the internet. So, could you help me with this?

Comment: @MrLY thank you for editing.

Comment: you are welcome @shaeredal good luck in your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set up artifacts in the deployment environment task.
More info [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/sharing-artifacts-359400060.html).